# ol start counter with css content counter not counting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to split a list into 2 separate columns evenly vertically and continue the numbering. I'm using `content: counter()`, `counter-reset` and `counter-increment`. The counter does start at the next number up but doesn't keep counting but repeats the same number over again.

```css
ol.rectangle-list {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
  *list-style: decimal;
  font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ol.rectangle-list ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}

.rectangle-list a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rectangle-list a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.rectangle-list a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  background: #fa8072;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rectangle-list.start-4 a:before {
  counter-reset: li 3;
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  background: #fa8072;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rectangle-list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  left: -1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rectangle-list a:hover:after {
  left: -.5em;
  border-left-color: #fa8072;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <ol class="rectangle-list">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <ol class="rectangle-list start-4">
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">6</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `counter-reset` on the element you're displaying the counter. You need to remove the `counter-reset` from the pseudo element and apply it to the parent instead.

```css
ol.rectangle-list {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
  *list-style: decimal;
  font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ol.rectangle-list ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}

.rectangle-list a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rectangle-list a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.rectangle-list a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  background: #fa8072;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rectangle-list.start-4 a:before {
  /* counter-reset: li 3; */
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  background: #fa8072;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rectangle-list.start-4 {
  counter-reset: li 3;
}

.rectangle-list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  left: -1em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rectangle-list a:hover:after {
  left: -.5em;
  border-left-color: #fa8072;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <ol class="rectangle-list">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <ol class="rectangle-list start-4">
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">6</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are resetting the counter on every new a element. Therefore, the counter will display the same number again, every time a new a-tag appears.

Try resetting the counter at only the ol element instead.